# Wicket appending weird number

Tags: java, wicket, wicket-1.5

I've figured a weird issue with Wicket 1.5.x. All of the sudden, wicket started to append a number that increases to every url which looks like mydomain.com/home?1. For every Bookmarkable link I click, wicket sends a redirect to the browser increasing that number. Same happens for when trying to clean the url and calling mydomain.com/home I end up with another redirect and an increased number.

What's even worse is that on Google App Engine the version number when clicking a link increase by the factor of two which also seems to cause issues with submitting forms which simply do.. well.. nothing!?

I've tried to play around with setVersioned(false)/true and setStatelessHint(false)/true without any result. What could that be, how to get rid of it and how can it influence my app not working on GAE?

thanks a bunch
Alex

EDIT:

It looks like wicket is always incrementing the version for my page as my base page is stateful (shows user's name if any in a model). But nothing changes on the site yet clicking i.e. my Bookmarkable Link to my home site increases it's page id with every click so if the user clicks 10x times on the home link his history is polluted with 10 entries of the *exactly* same page as nothing has changed.. this doesn't make any sense at all so I am curious how to fix that without loosing being stateful!?

Answer (score 5):

The number represents the version of the page. It appears when the page is stateful (thus the server must track its state).

It takes a little more than set the stateless hint to make a page stateless. You must avoid any component that holds state on the server side, and use stateless alternatives (`StatelessForm` instead of `Form`, `StatelessLink` instead of `Link`).

I answered this question with an example of a stateless page: [Is it difficult to make a mainly stateless web application with Wicket?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3431326/is-it-difficult-to-make-a-mainly-stateless-web-application-with-wicket)

Comment: Thanks but it looks like wicket is always incrementing the version for my page as my base page is stateful (shows user's name if any in a model). But nothing changes on the site yet clicking i.e. my Bookmarkable Link to my home site increases it's page id with every click so if the user clicks 10x times on the home link his history is polluted with 10 entries of the _exactly_ same page as nothing has changed.. this doesn't make any sense at all so I am curious how to fix that without loosing being stateful!?

Answer (score 1):

There is a Jira ticket: [setVersioned(false) should force single Page Version](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/WICKET-4087) about this issue. The question has also been discussed [in the mailing list](http://apache-wicket.1842946.n4.nabble.com/Stateful-versioned-bookmarkable-td4661990.html). Expected complications: [Page Reload on Submit of non-versioned Page](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/WICKET-4087)