# Nice URL: Wicket 1.5 mountPage

Tags: java, url, bookmarks, wicket-1.5

I am using Wicket 1.5.3 and in the extended WebApplication class I am registering home page, `HomePage.java` for pretty URL as:

```
mountPage('home', HomePage.class);
```

The result is a URL: http://localhost:8080/MyApplication/app/home?1

From where the "?1" came and how can I remove it?

If I want that the URL would be http://localhost:8080/MyApplication/app/home, then what should I do?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The parameter you see is the page version (because wicket pages are stateful). There is already a [SO question how to get rid of this version in url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8602489/delete-version-number-in-url).