# How to turn off redirect for one page in Wicket 1.5?

Tags: java, redirect, wicket, wicket-1.5

We are on Wicket 1.5 since 6 is not released yet. And I need to turn off redirect for one page (which does not have any meaningful forms on it).
How do I turn off redirect for one page in Wicket 1.5?

Edit:
We are on wicket 1.5 since wicketstuff is not released yet for wicket 6.
No meaningful forms means that we might have a search box there but no forms where users would have to enter valuable information. It is essentially product view page.

I mean redirect that redirects back to the same page with some id added. I'm not big expert in wicket, I've heard it is done by AJAX support to battle back button issues.

Edit2:
What I want is to remove redirect from my page even if it is stateful. Is it possible in Wicket?

Comment: *"does not have any meaningful forms on it"* ..it has meaningless forms?

Comment: FYI, 6.0.0 has actually been released: http://wicket.apache.org/2012/09/05/wicket-6.0.0-released.html

Comment: Which kind of redirect do you mean? Can you give an example?

Answer (score 0):

If by removing the redirect you just mean deleting page version number from the URL then see another Stack Overflow question: [delete version number in url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8602489/delete-version-number-in-url/8667136) .

If you also want to send some form via AJAX, there's [an example](http://www.wicket-library.com/wicket-examples/ajax/form) of that in Wicket Examples.