# Wicket: mounting clean URLs dynamically

Tags: java, wicket

I am developing a website about artists and I would like to have clean URLs like this:

```
http://www.example.com/artist/artistName
```

where `artistName` is the value entered in CMS. Currently I have URLs with this structure:

```
http://www.example.com/artist?0&name=artistName
```

This is what I did:

Added `mount(new MountedMapper("/artist", ArtistPage.class));` to web app's `init()` method and added `BookmarkablePageLink`:

`BookmarkablePageLink link = new BookmarkablePageLink("link", ArtistPage.class, params);`

How to make nice and clean URLs like in example at the very top of my post?

Answer (score 1):

The `?0` part ist the wicket page version number. It's used internally by wicket and not easily removed if your pages are statefull.

You can clean up the rest of the url by using something similar to

```
mountPage("/artist/${artistName}", ArtistPage.class);
```

This encodes the parameter `artistName` into the url.

Answer (score 0):

Wicket uses an id to identify the requested page and history of requested pages including page  and model versions.

If your page is stateful it is not a good idea to switch off that version system, probably you broke anything. See the question [delete version number in url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8602489/delete-version-number-in-url) .

If your page is stateless you can override the stateless hint of your page to notify wicket and the id is not included into the URL (also page is not redirected). See the example on stateful and stateless pages http://www.wicket-library.com/wicket-examples-6.0.x/stateless/ .