# Removing version in URL generated by wicket

Tags: java, wicket-1.6

I'm beginner with wicket framework and I'm trying to do this example (http://www.wicket-library.com/wicket-examples/captcha/). As expected, it works well.

But I'm trying now to remove the "?0" from the URL generated by wicket (for example, http://www.wicket-library.com/wicket-examples/captcha/?0). I read the documentation and saw the "setVersioned(false)" method to disable versioning of pages.

I added this method to CaptchaForm constructor but the "?0" is still there.

What do I need to do to remove the "version part" of the generated URL?

Comment: I don't think you can, its information that Wicket NEEDS to function. But I think it only needs it when you have stateful pages, so if you can make them stateless I think the number will disappear. But don't quote me on that.

Comment: I have same problem and that helps me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8602489/delete-version-number-in-url

Comment: Just as I expected, quote from that link: "Just for clarity, this does make your pages stateless so don't use this if you want statefull pages"