# How to delete version number in url for Wicket version 6.13.0 and newer ones?

Tags: wicket-6

The accepted solution given by
[delete version number in url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8602489/delete-version-number-in-url)

causes problems to AJAX for Wicket version 6.13.0 and newer ones. It keeps reloading the whole page endlessly.

-----Updated-----

Later I found out the following solution worked for me (wicket version 6.15.0) by setting the ONE_PASS_RENDER rendering strategy:

```java
class MyApplication extends WebApplication {
    @Override protected void init() {
        getRequestCycleSettings().setRenderStrategy(
            IRequestCycleSettings.RenderStrategy.ONE_PASS_RENDER); 
    }
}
```

It is suggested by https://stackoverflow.com/a/12422490/2700356

Comment: can you be more specific? I use Wicket 6.13.0 with exactly that solution.

Comment: This solution works for me: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12422490/2700356

Answer (score -1):

For Wicket 7 use this code:

```
getRequestCycleSettings().setRenderStrategy(RequestCycleSettings.RenderStrategy.ONE_PASS_RENDER);
```