# PageExpiredException occurs after closing of ModalWindow

Tags: wicket, wicket-6, modal-window

Currently I'm trying to upgrade the application from wicket 1.4 to wicket 6 and I'm stuck with the following issue:

When I try to close `ModalWindow`, it is closed but I receive `PageExpiredException` on the page where I was opening this `ModalWindow`, so I'm redirected to 
/myapp/wicket/bookmarkable/org.apache.wicket.markup.html.pages.PageExpiredErrorPage

I thought maybe the way I create `ModalWindow` is outdated, so I've tried an example from here

> http://www.wicket-library.com/wicket-examples-6.0.x/ajax/modal-window?0

and it gives me the same exception.

Maybe I have to configure something in my `WebApplication` implementation, but I don't know what.
If anyone could help, it'll be really appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: http://www.wicket-library.com/wicket-examples-6.0.x/ajax/modal-window works fine for me. There is no PageExpiredException.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your server logs for errors related to the serialization of the opener page. PageExpiredException means that the page cannot be found in the page storage. If there was an error with the serialization then it won't be stored and thus later won't be found too.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Martin!
Now I got rid of this issue: in my WebApplication I was using the following [solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8667136/4164758) to delete pageId from url. When I removed it, my ModalWindows started to work fine. I guess I just have to find another solution on how to remove pageId from url :)