# Apache Wicket: Remove or alter presentation of pageId from statefull pages

Tags: wicket, wicket-6, wicket-1.6

Is it possible to remove the pageId from the URL of a statefull wicket page? It's ok if it's not versioned in the page store because of this.

I've tried overriding the isVersioned()-method to returning false, but I still get the pageId in the URL:

http://localhost:8080/appname/s/frontpage/?**11**

Or - even better - is it possible to alter the presentation by assigning the pageId to a parameter like this:

http://localhost:8080/appname/s/frontpage/?**pageId=11**

and thus keep the page statefull?

The reason I would want to do this is because the pageId creates lots of different URLs in my google analytics dashboard which in reality is the same URL:

http://localhost:8080/appname/s/frontpage/?0
http://localhost:8080/appname/s/frontpage/?1
http://localhost:8080/appname/s/frontpage/?2
http://localhost:8080/appname/s/frontpage/?3

etc...

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Please check http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/wicket-users/201210.mbox/%3CCAAJwaYWaP0Vdn4xmpWSf8Bj-e_m536LAyhn7M9b6sxEcM_RfQQ@mail.gmail.com%3E

And maybe also this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8667136/497381